# Remove Multiple Trailing Characters in SQL Server - Oracle equivalent to Trim (Trailing)

Tags: sql-server, trim, trailing

I have a table with a field that acts like an array for some front-end processing and that is the result of concatenating 9 columns from a different flat table. The field was populated as such

> Field1 + ',' + Field2 + ',' + Field3 + ',' + Field4 + ',' + Field5 + ',' + Field6 + ',' + Field7 + ',' + Field8 + ',' + Field9

If Field4 from the flat table has a value, then Fields 1, 2 and 3 also have a value. But, most of the time Fields 5 – 9 do not have values. The result is that most values in the array field (after the concatenation) look like this:

> Bob,Joe,Mary,Sam,,,,,

I am looking for a simple way to update this concatenated field to instead look like this:

```
Bob,Joe,Mary,Sam
```

This is the Oracle equivalent to `Trim(Trailing',' From FieldValue)`

Answer (score 3):

I would go with a reverse, find the first non-comma char, then use that in conjunction with a LEN() and LEFT()

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(200) = 'Bob,Joe,Mary,Sam,,,,,'

SELECT LEFT(@string, LEN(@string) - PATINDEX('%[^,]%', REVERSE(@string))+1)
```

Comment: --This is cool, but failes for the following:
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(200) = 'Bob1,Joe2,Mary3,Sam4,,,,,'
SELECT LEFT(@string, LEN(@string) - PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', REVERSE(@string))+1)

Comment: The code has been updated to find the first non-comma character thanks to Martin's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Create the following UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Trailing(@String VarChar(Max), @Char VarChar(5))
RETURNS VarChar(Max)
BEGIN
    RETURN
        Reverse(
        SubString(
        Reverse(@String)
        ,PatIndex('%[^' + @Char + ' ]%',Reverse(@String))
        ,DataLength(@String)
        )
        )
END
GO
```

Give it a test drive:

```
SELECT
    'Array_Value_1,Array_Value_2,Array_Value_3,,,,,' AS Original_String,
    dbo.Trailing('Array_Value_1,Array_Value_2,Array_Value_3,,,,,', ',') AS Clean_String
GO
```

Comment: Personally I wouldn't reverse the string three times. You need to do it once but then you can calculate the bit of the string you need by subtracting the patindex from the length.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply do this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(@str, ',,', '');
```

You will be left with a string with 1 or 0 commas at the end, depending on whether there were an even or odd number of trailing commas.

You can wrap this in a SUBSTRING or LEFT construct that removes the last character if it's a comma.